# Firestore batch delete don't work while using emulator with react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I want to try some code with firestore emulator before using it in production, I want basically to retrieve a collection documents sort them and set them again in the collection:
I have this error while doing a batch delete :

`[Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.]`

the code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await admin_sortUserRanksDB()
        })()
    }, [])
    const admin_sortUserRanksDB = async () => {
        const usersData = await admin_getUserDataDBAndClean()
        populateUserCollection(usersData)
    }

    const admin_getUserDataDBAndClean = async () => {
        try {
            const querySnapshot = await firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .orderBy('experience_amount', 'desc')
                .get();
            let rank = 1;
            let newDataUsers = [];
            for (const user of querySnapshot.docs) {
                const userData = user.data();
                userData.rank = rank;
                newDataUsers.push(userData)
                rank++
            }
                await deleteUserCollection(querySnapshot)
           
            return newDataUsers;
        } catch (error) {
            if (!__DEV__) {
                crashlytics().log(
                    `error getUserDataDB() 
                          userActions.js ===>> ${error.message}`
                );
            }
            console.log('error getUserDataDB ', error)
            return null
        }
    }

    const deleteUserCollection = async (usersQuerySnapshot) => {
        // Create a new batch instance
        const batch = firestore().batch();

        usersQuerySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            batch.delete(documentSnapshot.ref);
        });
        console.log('==============')
        return batch.commit();
    }

    const populateUserCollection = usersData => {
        if (usersData) {
            const batch = firestore().batch();
            usersData.forEach(doc => {
                let docRef = firestore()
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(); //automatically generate unique id
                batch.set(docRef, doc);
            });
            batch
                .commit()
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error populating users', error)
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting an issue to `react-native-firebase` repo i was suggested to modify my rules to be open (only locally) and the batch delete worked.

I used the `allow read, write: if true`  in firestore.rules file

[link to issue on GitHub](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4842)